# winexpect import in a .py not working when running through cmd

Tags: python-2.7, cmd, pexpect

Why I am getting this error, when I try to run it through `python corenlp.py`?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "corenlp.py", line 23, in (module)
from winpexpect import winspawn
File "C:\Python27\1ib\site-packages\winpexpect-1.5-py2.7.egg\winpexpect.py", 1ine 391, in (module)
class winspawn(spawn):
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
function() argument 1 must be code, not str
```

But, When i use it in PythonShell GUI, it is working perfectly.

```
from winpexpect import winspawn
child = winspawn('java -cp "C:\\Python27\\Scripts\\stanford-corenlp-full-2014-08-27\\*" -Xmx2g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,dcoref -ner.model edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.all.3class.caseless.distsim.crf.ser.gz')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to resolve my problem(Thanks to @MichaelPetch). I tried this simple example `test.py`

```
from winpexpect import winspawn
child=winspawn("java")
```

It was working fine. Then I realized something wrong with my imports or dependencies. I was using  [wexpect.py](https://gist.github.com/anthonyeden/8488763) which is another alternative for windows. I renamed it to `pexpect.py` and copied to my code base.

But `winpexpect` has dependencies for pexpect(it has another pexpect file on its own folder). When I try to run my .py through cmd it is referring the file in the same folder which is pexpect, I just renamed.

Solution: I just removed `wexpect`.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error locally because your Python27 doesn't have a prerequisite component installed. In particular it needs Pywin32 installed. You need to download and install Pywin32 from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20219/) (specifically the 2.7 version in your case). PythonShell GUI must have this extension already installed so it works.

Comment: If it is installed what happens if you try doing `import win32api` ? does it load without an error?

Comment: I would be curious what happens if you do an `import win32api` prior to `from winpexpect import winspawn` and then do your winspawn call.

Comment: Finally, resolved! I was using [pexpect.py](https://gist.github.com/anthonyeden/8488763) in the same folder, which is another alternative for win. Then `winpexpect` has dependencies for `pexpect`. When I try to run through `cmd` it is referring the file in the same folder. I just removed it. Thank you very much!